# C++ API for Raspberry pi camera not working

Tags: raspicam

I am new with R-pi. I need to use picam. While working with cpp, i came to know there are already different API for this. I am using an API link here: http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40 . Has anyone used it before because i am not able to run my program even while using cmake, like:

#

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8) 
project (project_name)
find_package(path_to_raspicam REQUIRED)
add_executable (project project.cpp)
target_link_libraries (project ${raspicam_LIBS})

###############################.

Also if i am going to use gcc command like:

g++ project.cpp -o project -I/usr/local/include -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util

there is not anything like "-I/usr/local/include -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util"

Please tell me how to include the library and make executable file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you compile the API/library ? Were there any errors ?  What do you mean by `there is not anything like "-I/usr/local/include -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util"` ?  What output / errors do you get when trying to compile ?

Comment: sorry for incomplete post. Actually there is no such thing like -lmmal etc in /usr/local. Terminal also showed the error of non-existence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded the API, compiled it as per the [instructions on this page](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40). I then used the sample app code (on the same page) and tried to compile it as per their instructions with :

```
g++ simpletest_raspicam.cpp -o simpletest_raspicam -I/usr/local/include -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util
```

This gave me errors as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal-core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal_util
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Google found me [this page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=67381&p=493335) which suggests adding a hint for the linker to where the mmal libraries are, like this:

```
-L/opt/vc/lib
```

I added that to my compiling command to make it:

```
g++ simpletest_raspicam.cpp -o simpletest_raspicam -I/usr/local/include -L/opt/vc/lib -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util
```

... and it compiled successfully.

Answer (score 2):

> there is not anything like "-I/usr/local/include -lraspicam -lmmal -lmmal_core -lmmal_util"

As KennetRunner points out this is because those libraries aren't in the linker's default path. It is worth mentioning that there are **two** of these to consider, the linker used at *compile time* and the shared object linker used at *runtime* if there are shared libraries linked (which there usually are).

The paths searched by the compile time linker are essentially hardcoded into it, so you need to explicitly use `-L/opt/vc/lib`.

You then need to make sure the runtime linker can find the relevant libraries.  To add a path for that:

```
sudo bash echo /opt/vc/lib/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opt-vc.conf
```

Then run `sudo ldconfig` to update the linker cache, and to verify,

```
sudo ldconfig -p | grep mmal
```

(see `man ldconfig` about `-p`).  You should see a few lines about those libraries.

If the base C includes are useful too (in addition to those of the C++ wrapper library in `/usr/local/include`), those won't be in the *compiler's* default path, so you could use `-I /opt/vc/include` or else add to your environment:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/vc/include
```

If you already have such a path set you can expand it the way you would expand the ordinary path variable (e.g. `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/opt/vc/include`).